# Arduino Uno with color sensor TCS3200 RGB

Tags: colors, arduino, rgb

I'm trying to make a simple program with an Arduino Uno and sensor TCS3200. I want to catch the RGB value of the scanned color, but the output doesn't seem an RGB code because the values are over 255 and they do not match with the real color. I think that the values returned are frequencies of the colors.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#define S0 4
#define S1 5
#define S2 6
#define S3 7
#define sensorOut 8
int frequency = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(S0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensorOut, INPUT);

  // Setting frequency-scaling to 20%
  digitalWrite(S0,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S1,LOW);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  // Setting red filtered photodiodes to be read
  digitalWrite(S2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(S3,LOW);
  // Reading the output frequency
  frequency = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
  //Remaping the value of the frequency to the RGB Model of 0 to 255
  frequency = map(frequency, 25,72,255,0);
  // Printing the value on the serial monitor
  Serial.print("R= ");//printing name
  Serial.print(frequency);//printing RED color frequency
  Serial.print("  ");
  delay(100);
  // Setting Green filtered photodiodes to be read
  digitalWrite(S2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S3,HIGH);
  // Reading the output frequency
  frequency = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
  //Remaping the value of the frequency to the RGB Model of 0 to 255
  frequency = map(frequency, 30,90,255,0);
  // Printing the value on the serial monitor
  Serial.print("G= ");//printing name
  Serial.print(frequency);//printing RED color frequency
  Serial.print("  ");
  delay(100);
  // Setting Blue filtered photodiodes to be read
  digitalWrite(S2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(S3,HIGH);
  // Reading the output frequency
  frequency = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
  //Remaping the value of the frequency to the RGB Model of 0 to 255
  frequency = map(frequency, 25,70,255,0);
  // Printing the value on the serial monitor
  Serial.print("B= ");//printing name
  Serial.print(frequency);//printing RED color frequency
  Serial.println("  ");
  delay(100);
}
```

Is there a way to turn the frequency values into an accurate RGB color?

Edit: here is a scan of a grey material:

```
R= 174  G= 200  B= 340  
R= 174  G= 200  B= 317  
R= 174  G= 200  B= 323  
R= 174  G= 200  B= 323  
R= 174  G= 200  B= 323  
R= 174  G= 200  B= 323  
R= 180  G= 204  B= 323  
R= 185  G= 209  B= 323  
R= 180  G= 209  B= 323  
R= 185  G= 209  B= 323  
R= 185  G= 209  B= 323  
R= 218  G= 209  B= 323  
R= 185  G= 209  B= 328
```

Comment: Why you don't show us a sample of output?

Comment: Here is an output of a scan of a grey material : R= 174  G= 200  B= 340  
R= 174  G= 200  B= 317  
R= 174  G= 200  B= 323  
R= 174  G= 200  B= 323  
R= 174  G= 200  B= 323  
R= 174  G= 200  B= 323  
R= 180  G= 204  B= 323  
R= 185  G= 209  B= 323  
R= 180  G= 209  B= 323  
R= 185  G= 209  B= 323  
R= 185  G= 209  B= 323  
R= 218  G= 209  B= 323  
R= 185  G= 209  B= 328